# How to change an image source on hover?

Tags: jquery, html, image

I want to change image source using jQuery but with animation.

I have a default straight looking image. I have 5 different images with a head looking at different directions.
on hover of a particular section, I want to change the image to that particular image `src` value.

If no div is hovered, the default straight looking image should appear.

I have achieved it but the images should change with an animation. My animations are flickering.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

```js
$('#thumbs img').hover(function(event) {

  $(this).fadeOut(100, function() {
    var thisSRC = $(this).attr('src');
    $('#main').attr('src', thisSRC);
  }).fadeIn(100);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="thumbs">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/rxX8VMq/left.png" width="50" height="50">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/r77CrCC/topleft.png" width="50" height="50">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/CzRdRtp/top.png" width="50" height="50">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/L8cSs3p/topright.png" width="50" height="50">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/D1cjqfD/right.png" width="50" height="50">
</div>

<img id="main" src="https://i.ibb.co/3dMWhqV/default-head.png">
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamm_98666/1d0L6emq/)

Comment: 100 is 100 milliseconds, which is an extremely short period of time.  If you want a more gradual fadeOut/fadeIn, increase that duration

Comment: You'll probably want to `.finish()` the queued animation before starting another. Currently if you hover over a bunch, it's going to start triggering animations in weird orders etc.

Comment: @Taplar I know the duration is short but the animation is not as desired. may be the function I am using is not correct.

Comment: So elaborate on that.  What **is** the desired animation?

Comment: @TylerRoper can you help me out with it

Comment: @Taplar I need the animation to be smoother. even if I change it to 500 its not being smoother.

Comment: I see multiple issues, and like Taplar, I don't know which one you're trying to address. Your `hover` should probably be `mouseenter`. You should use `.finish()` to complete previous actions before starting new ones.

Comment: Are you trying to animate the thumbnails or the main image...?

Comment: @TylerRoper I want the main image to animate smoother.

Comment: The main image currently isn't animating *at all*. Your current code animates the thumbnails, which is why when you say "I want the animation to be smoother", there is confusion. Janos's answer below addresses this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194905/discussion-between-mohammed-wahed-khan-and-tyler-roper).

Answer (score 2):

Given the fact you are using the full-size images **already**, then a CSS-only solution could be used, since no additional bandwidth is needed to load the large pictures:

## CSS-only:

```css
.thumb{ 
  width: 50px; 
  display: inline-block;
}

.thumb:hover  ~ .big .default{ opacity:0; }


.thumb:nth-child(1):hover ~ .big > img:nth-child(1){ z-index:5; opacity:1; }
.thumb:nth-child(2):hover ~ .big > img:nth-child(2){ z-index:5; opacity:1; }
.thumb:nth-child(3):hover ~ .big > img:nth-child(3){ z-index:5; opacity:1; }
.thumb:nth-child(4):hover ~ .big > img:nth-child(4){ z-index:5; opacity:1; }
.thumb:nth-child(5):hover ~ .big > img:nth-child(5){ z-index:5; opacity:1; }

.big{ position:relative; } 
.big img{ 
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .2s .1s ease-out;
}

.big .default{ opacity:1; }
```

```html
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/rxX8VMq/left.png" class='thumb'>
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/r77CrCC/topleft.png" class='thumb'>
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/CzRdRtp/top.png" class='thumb'>
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/L8cSs3p/topright.png" class='thumb'>
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/D1cjqfD/right.png" class='thumb'>

<div class='big'>
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/rxX8VMq/left.png">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/r77CrCC/topleft.png">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/CzRdRtp/top.png" class='default'>
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/L8cSs3p/topright.png">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/D1cjqfD/right.png">
</div>
```

It's **much** easier to generate the above CSS using pre-processors (like SCSS)

Answer (score 1):

```js
  $('#thumbs img').hover(function(event){
   $('#thumbs img').finish();    
        var thisSRC=$(this).attr('src');
        $('#main').fadeTo(500, 0.5);
        $('#main').finish();
        $('#main').fadeTo(500, 1).attr('src',thisSRC);        
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="thumbs">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/rxX8VMq/left.png" width="50" height="50">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/r77CrCC/topleft.png" width="50" height="50">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/CzRdRtp/top.png" width="50" height="50">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/L8cSs3p/topright.png" width="50" height="50">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/D1cjqfD/right.png" width="50" height="50">
</div>

<img id="main" src="https://i.ibb.co/3dMWhqV/default-head.png">
```

Comment: even now the images are flickering on hover.

Comment: Its because, all hover cast by time.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Merajkhan/pen/dBPZZP this is my desired output but with images

Comment: I dont think so, you could do this only jpg or png file. :(

Comment: can you suggest me how can I do it? should I create svg's for that?

Comment: I am so impressed on my last update. have a look. If you think its getting closer to your output. then let me know, any changes. :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok so this is a modified version that animates the main, not any of the thumbnails.

- On hover the thumbnail gets a class of `active`

  - The main image is faded out
  - The main is replaced with the src of the thumbnail
  - The main is faded in
- On hover end, remove the class `active` from the thumbnail

  - Start a timeout of 300 milliseconds

    - If no thumbnail is active after 300 milliseconds, revert the main back to the default image

```js
var $thumbnails = $('#thumbs img');
var $main = $('#main');

$main.data('originalSrc', $main.attr('src'));

$thumbnails.on('mouseenter', function(e){
  e.target.classList.add('active');
  
  $main.finish().fadeOut(500, function(){
    $main.attr('src', e.target.getAttribute('src'));
    $main.fadeIn(500);
  });
});

$thumbnails.on('mouseleave', function(e){
  e.target.classList.remove('active');
  
  setTimeout(function(){
    if ($thumbnails.filter('.active').length < 1) {
      $main.prop('src', $main.data('originalSrc'));
    }
  }, 200);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="thumbs">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/rxX8VMq/left.png" width="50" height="50">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/r77CrCC/topleft.png" width="50" height="50">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/CzRdRtp/top.png" width="50" height="50">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/L8cSs3p/topright.png" width="50" height="50">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/D1cjqfD/right.png" width="50" height="50">
</div>

<img id="main" src="https://i.ibb.co/3dMWhqV/default-head.png">
```

Comment: can we change the jquery whatever I'm using like the fadeout and fade in to animate.

Comment: What animation are you after? @MohammedWahedKhan

Comment: @Taplar After a bit of clarification in the comments, it sounds like the main image itself is supposed to be animated as opposed to the thumbnails.

Comment: @TylerRoper https://codepen.io/Merajkhan/pen/dBPZZP this is the desired output but using images

Comment: @MohammedWahedKhan I've modified the answer to animate only the main image, and it also restores it once all thumbnails are not hovered.

Comment: @Taplar can you look at the codepen link I have commented and give some suggestions on how to achieve it. I'll try my best.

Comment: That codepen has an animation related to mousemove on the page, not on hovering images.  That example and what you are asking for in your question are completely different

Answer (score 0):

You should `fadeOut` first and when it's finished, change the source and do a `fadeIn` in the finished callback.

```js
$('#thumbs img').hover(function(event) {
  var thisSRC = $(this).attr('src');
  $('#main').fadeOut(300, function() {
    $('#main').attr('src', thisSRC);
    $('#main').fadeIn(300)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="thumbs">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/rxX8VMq/left.png" width="50" height="50">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/r77CrCC/topleft.png" width="50" height="50">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/CzRdRtp/top.png" width="50" height="50">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/L8cSs3p/topright.png" width="50" height="50">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/D1cjqfD/right.png" width="50" height="50">
</div>

<img id="main" src="https://i.ibb.co/3dMWhqV/default-head.png">
```